# Oracle Database service running but cannot connect

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having the following trouble. I have created three different database schemas in my laptop, each has a different service.

I activate and deactivate the service that I want to use each time. But I have been facing a problem after I created the third schema.

[Task Manager - Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcOHN.png)

When I activate the OracleServiceIANBG I am able to connect properly through SQL developer in that instance. When I deactivate it and activate one of the other two instances, the corresponding connections in the SQL developer that I have created are giving me the following error:

```
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

[SQL Developer snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa3xp.png)

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can troubleshoot it?

Comment: schemas don't have a service, only the database has a service...when you say 'schema', do you mean a new database or a new pluggable database? do you have more than one listener configured? one listener can handle 3 databases, no problem

Comment: also in 12, it's better to use the service name, not the SID in your connection properties, and it's mandatory if you're trying to connect to a pluggable database

Comment: Is IANBG the only one you can connect to? Or, if you restart the PC, then start any of the Oracle services, you can connect to that service, but closing that and starting another makes the active one inaccessible?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith yes sorry wrong wording! When you say the service name do you mean the OracleServiceORASD for example? Because I have tried that and it does nothing, even to the connections that are working. I only have one listener configured, yes.

Comment: @TenG When I restart the PC, all three services are up and running and I cannot connect to any service. When I stop 2 of these services and leave 1 active, I can connect only when the active service is the IANBG.

Comment: how many databases do you have on your machine?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith 3 databases

Comment: run lsnrctl status at a cmd prompt and confirm all 3 services are listed

Comment: @thatjeffsmith it gives me an output only for the working service. The other 2 services are like non-existent.

Comment: @Tsosmis that's why you can't connect then..however, in SQL Developer you can also do a bequeath connection - that bypasses the listener, but only avail when SQLDev and the db are on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

On your cmd line check `lsnrctl` and see what services are running.

```
>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 13-NOV-2018 14:15:59

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                13-NOV-2018 14:15:36
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 23 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/c132613c345e/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "64a52f53a7683286e053cda9e80aed76" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "758e766d38d80b9de053020011acb4c6" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

If the expected services are not listed, they can be registered with an alter system register command.

```
sqlplus  / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Nov 13 14:17:28 2018
Version 18.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter system register;

System altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

just enter the ./sqlplus  command.

it should prompt for username:

username:  "sys as sysdba"  use this entire phrase
password:  {password during installation}

then it should connect

but if you want to connect to the instance: like oraclxdba

you should use an external SQL management tool right? then you can just specify the SID you want to connect to with the same username and password